# just queries. List the birthday of receivers who order “shoes”.2.List the name of carriers who deliver orders of the lowest and the highest price

Tags: sql

[CARRIER table]

```
Carrier_ID        Name        Gender      Birthday  


2001              Aylin       Female      29.03.1975 
2002              Arif        Male        29.09.1996 
2003              Berker      Male        13.11.1970 
2004              Sezgin      Male        13.06.1988 
2005              Yeliz       Female      11.08.1951 
2006              Dolunay     Male        17.07.1974 
2007              Reşide      Female      10.01.1960 
2008              Münir       Male        27.06.1989
```

[ORDER table]

Order_ID     Description              Price      Carrier_ID

```
1001             24” Monitor           199          2001 
1002             Cloths                45           2003 
1003             Vaporizer             24           2006 
1004             Book                  19           2002 
1005             Graphics Card         450          2003 
1006             Shoes                 37           2007 
1007             Bag                   14           2008 
1008             Processor             299          2008
```

Comment: Please provide more information in your question. It would be best if you could provide any queries you have tried, along with your table structure, as well as your current results / sample table content and what you want your desired output should look like. Also read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Edit your question and add the relevant information to it instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: Are "shoes" defined by a particular `Carrier_ID`? What defines an order of "shoes"?

Comment: Ok, you've now changed the question entirely. Also, you should really have a simple description of the problem in the title and put a well thought out and written, extended question in the body. That is where you should have all of the details related to your question... not in the title. With that said, it still is not clear what you really want. Adding examples of your desired output would be of the greatest help to provide the answer you are looking for.

Comment: ı just want how to write the 2 queris in my question basd on the two table. taht is all

Comment: When you submit questions in the future, read through the link I posted above ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ). Following the guidelines on that page will give you the best chances of getting your question answered. Some of the main things to keep in mind is #1: provide as much relevant information as you can (but try to keep it as simple as possible too). This includes any simplified samples of data and the related table structures. Both of what you are working with, and what your desired output should resemble. A close #2: Include queries you have attempted. It's important...

Comment: ... to show what you have done to prevent duplication of work. More importantly, it shows that you have at least put in some effort on your own.And it may also provide clues as to what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: thank you. this was my first time triyng such thing. I will try harder

Comment: Sure. If my answer is what you were looking for, please upvote and accept it as the answer. If it is not correct, then please add a comment to it to clarify what part is incorrect and I can make any adjustments before you accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to put this together with the little bit of information you have available in your post, and in the comment you left... It appears that you have two tables `Carrier` and `Order`. First of all, I do see in the `Order` table, you have entries with a `Description` of "Shoes". I would hope though, that you would have a lookup table that contains an entry for each of your products / order types, but just going on what you have given us so far, the less ideal approach would be:

For your first question:

> List the birthday of recievers who order “shoes”

```
select c.Birthday
from Carrier c
join Order o
on o.Carrier_ID = c.Carrier_ID
where o.Description = 'Shoes';
```

Ideally, you should have a lookup table for your products/order types that would contain a unique identifier and the description of the product. You should then store the unique identifier in the order table instead of the description. Then you would join to the product lookup table to get the information about that product.

With the newly provided information, here is likely a better query which does the same as the first one, but more properly:

```
select c.Birthday
from Carrier c
join Order o
on o.Carrier_ID = c.Carrier_ID
where o.Order_ID = 1006;
```

As for part two of your question:

> List the name of carriers who deliver orders of the lowest and the highest price.

```
with MinPrice_CTE (MinPrice)
as
(
   select Min(Price) as MinPrice
   from Orders
),
MaxPrice_CTE (MaxPrice)
as
(
   select Max(Price) as MaxPrice
   from Orders
)
select c.Name, 
   case when o.Price = MinPrice then 'Minimum Price' 
   else 'Maximum Price' end as PriceGroup
from Carriers c
join Orders o
on o.Carrier_ID = c.Carrier_ID
where o.Price in (MinPrice, MaxPrice);
```

Comment: is there any way we can do it with nested query

Comment: Why do you want a nested query? What data do you want in your final results? Update your question to include a sample output for your desired results and I can modify my query to match.

Comment: @RabiaAydınkaya I have updated my answer to handle both of your questions. Give those queries a shot and let me know if that worked out for you.